# Angular : Form, childs components, subject subcription and events ordering Problem

Tags: angular, forms, events, viewchild

I have a main form which embeds several child components.
The main form component gets data from an API server using service and subject subscription :

Main.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'zorg',
  templateUrl: './zorg.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./zorg.component.scss']
})
export class ZorgComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  
  @ViewChild(FooComponent) FooComp: FooComponent;
  @ViewChild(BarrComponent) BarComp: QuoteLaBarrComponentyerComponent;

  destroy$: Subject<boolean> = new Subject<boolean>();

  mandatObjSubscription: Subscription;
  mandatoryObjects: {....}={...};


  constructor(
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private zorgService: QuoteService,
    ...
    ) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.initForm();
    
    this.mandatObjSubscription=this.zorgService.mandatObjSubject$.takeUntil(this.destroy$).subscribe(
        (data)=> {
            this.mandatoryObjects=data;
            console.log('OBJ RECEVIED');
            console.log(JSON.stringify(this.mandatoryObjects));
        },
        (error) => {
        },
    );

    var ZorgId;
    this.zorgIdSubscription = this.activatedRoute.paramMap.pipe(
        map((params: ParamMap) => +params.get('id')),
        tap(zorgId => {
            //API REQUEST IS MADE HERE
            this.zorgService.getMandatoryObjectsFromRest();
        }),
        filter(zorgId => !!zorgId),
        tap(zorgId => ZorgId=zorgId),
        ...
    ).takeUntil(this.destroy$).subscribe();
    
  }
  
  initForm() {
    this.zorgForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      id: '',
      label: ['', [Validators.required]],
      foo: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, SelectedValue]),
      bar: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
    });
  
}
```

my sub-components also need access to these data, therefore, I subscribe to the same subject.

Foo.compoenent.ts

```
// describes what the return value of the form control will look like
export interface fooFormValues {
    ...
}

@Component({
  selector: 'ngx-foo,
  templateUrl: './foo.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./foo.component.scss'],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => FooComponent),
      multi: true
    },
    {
      provide: NG_VALIDATORS,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => FooComponent),
      multi: true
    }
  ]
})

export class FooComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy, ControlValueAccessor {

  @Input() inEntityName: string;
  @Input() inErrors: any[];

  destroy$: Subject<boolean> = new Subject<boolean>();

  mandatObjSubscription: Subscription;
  mandatObjs;
    
  fooForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private zorgService: ZorgService,
    ...
    ) { 
        console.log('FOOCONSTRUCT');
    }

  ngOnInit(): void {
        this.entityName= this.inEntityName;
        console.log('FOO INTI');
        this.initForm();
        this.mandatObjSubscription=this.zorgService.mandatObjSubject$.takeUntil(this.destroy$).subscribe(
            objects => {
                this.mandatObjs=objects[this.entityName];
                console.log('OBJMISC RECEIVED');
            }
        );
        this.fooForm.valueChanges.takeUntil(this.destroy$).subscribe(value => {
            this.onChange(value);
            this.onTouched();
        });
  }
```

As I was getting non-present value error I added consol.log to track the issue and noticed that some of my subcomponents are initialized after the mandatory Objects reception...

How can I solve this?

Thank you for your help

EDIT 1 :

here is how my subcomponent Foo is inserted into main template:

```
<ngx-foo *ngIf="mandatoryObjects.foos.length > 0" id="fooComp" formControlName="foo" inEntityName="foo" [inErrors]="">
</ngx-foo>
```

Comment: you sub-compnents is ngx-foo? how do you insert in the main template?

Comment: thank you for your help, yes Foo is one of my sub-compoenents type. I have several but all the same principle. please see my edit

Comment: pass your object as attribute, with @Input, check the answer bellow